# How to retrive values of radio buttons , checkboxes and multiple select in edit form in laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my edit view

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputGender">Your Gender</label><br />
             <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="gender" @if($student['gender'] == 'male') checked @endif> Male</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="gender" @if($student['gender'] == 'female') checked @endif> Female</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="gender" @if($student['gender'] == 'others') checked @endif> Others</label>
            </div> 

<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputHobbies">Your Hobbies</label><br />
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="football" name="hobbies[]" checked> Football</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="dancing" name="hobbies[]"> Dancing</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="hacking" name="hobbies[]"> Hacking</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="singing" name="hobbies[]"> Singing</label>
            </div> 
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputNationality">Select your Languages (Can Select Multiple)</label>
            <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="sel1" name="languages[]">
              <option value="">Nepali</option>
              <option value="">Hindi</option>
              <option value="">Korean</option>
              <option value="">Bangladeshi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

I have passed all the values through controllers and routes .Now I want to get all the values selected while creating or adding the form in this edit form while editing . How to dot it . Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are storing multiple values form hobbies and languages but the main thing is you need array of both things

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputGender">Your Gender</label><br />
             <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="gender" @if($student['gender'] == 'male') checked @endif> Male</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="gender" @if($student['gender'] == 'female') checked @endif> Female</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="gender" @if($student['gender'] == 'others') checked @endif> Others</label>
            </div> 
@php $hobbies = explode(',',$student['hobbies']); @endphp
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputHobbies">Your Hobbies</label><br />
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="football" name="hobbies[]" @if(in_array('football',$hobbies)) checked @endif> Football</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="dancing" name="hobbies[]" @if(in_array('dancing',$hobbies)) checked @endif> Dancing</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="hacking" name="hobbies[]" @if(in_array('hacking',$hobbies)) checked @endif> Hacking</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="singing" name="hobbies[]"> Singing</label>
            </div> 
        </div>
@php $languages = explode(',',$student['languages']); @endphp
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputNationality">Select your Languages (Can Select Multiple)</label>
            <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="sel1" name="languages[]">
              <option value="Nepali" @if(in_array('Nepali',$languages)) selected @endif>Nepali</option>
              <option value="Hindi" @if(in_array('Hindi',$languages)) selected @endif>Hindi</option>
              <option value="Korean" @if(in_array('Korean',$languages)) selected @endif>Korean</option>
              <option value="Bangladeshi" @if(in_array('Bangladeshi',$languages)) selected @endif>Bangladeshi</option>
            </select>


        </div>
```

Comment: I am storing in array

Comment: then simple return all data on edit page and use like above

Comment: It says undefined variable $hobbies

Comment: I have stored by implode method

Comment: means comma separated, so when in your page make array by $hobbies=explode(',', $student['hobbies'])